# Standard deviation values from t.test(x,y) command in rstudio

Tags: r

I am new to coding. I recently did a t-test on my variables where the the variable in one column was divided into two groups so that I can use the command, t.test(Data$Numbers ~ Data$Outcome, data = Data).

This command gave me 2 mean values of the column "Numbers", that was divided into two groups based on the results in the column "Outcome". The outcome was "disease" or "No disease". So it separated the column "Numbers" into two groups: disease v/s No disease.

It gave me the mean and the CI of the groups but it didn't give me the standard deviation value. What code I can use to get those values as well?

I used the stat_summary command but I am getting weird values.

Comment: The standard deviation of what? `sd(x)` and `sd(y)`?

Comment: of both x and y. The command I used was: t.test(Data$Numbers~Data$Outcome, data = Data).

Comment: You should use `t.test(Numbers ~ Outcome, data = Data)`. The t-test function does not return the standard deviations of your variables. Use e.g. `with(Data, tapply(Numbers, Outcome, sd))`.